# Slick Slider - slide from left to right

Tags: wordpress, slider, slick.js

Just wondering if anyone can help please.

I'm using Slick Slider on one my WordPress sites, and the slider is currently sliding from right to left. I'd like the slider to slide from left to right when it changes slides.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fadex').slick({
    dots: false,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3500,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: false, 
    initialSlide: 0,
    arrows: true,
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: it is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557395/4-custom-post-types-per-slick-slider?

Comment: That's all working fine. I think its just a general slider thing, most don't seem to slide that way so I've left the problem for now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

rtl : [slick-slider rtl=”true”] (for rtl mode. By default value is “false”. Options are “true OR false”).

Simply use the options provided. By default value is “false”, change this to true, or vice versa to change the direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fadex').slick({
    dots: false,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3500,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: false, 
    initialSlide: 0,
    arrows: true,
    rtl: true,

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to just at 'rtl: true,' or do I need to add any code to my slider itself. Some documentation said I'd also have to add some code to the slider itself.

Comment: if you add it to the code in the js file. it will apply the RTL to all sliders.
If you add RTL to the shortocde parameters options, it will only apply to that specific slider.
So the answer is both, depending if you want it applied across all sliders or just one.

Comment: I've got the slider setup as an ACF Repeater. When I add rtl: true, it just breaks the slider and goes completely white :(

Comment: There's quite a lot of code, so I've chopped it right back to include important parts for you...

<div class="hero-slider" style="height: 510px;">
 <div class="fadex"><div>

Then obviously all the divs are closed.

Comment: little confused here. are you not using the shortcode? to output the slider?
How do you have the slick slider installed?

Comment: I'm not using the slick slider plugin, i'm using the js within my theme, and then the slick slider is coded in with html, php/acf

Comment: understood :)
Are you adding rtl: true inside your js file? Like above
Do you have the , before arrows options?

Comment: also, do you have any console errors? if so what are they?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem requires you to change the style of the left value

Because it adds a negative to the **single-product-image** class

Inside the **slick.js** file at **line 866**

Add a new line and add this condition

```
if($("html").attr("dir") == 'rtl'){ var newE = t.slideWidth * o; }else{ var newE = t.slideWidth * o * -1; }
```

And change this condition

```
(e = t.slideWidth * o * -1)
```

to this

```
(e = newE)
```

Then the page orientation will be relied upon in the case of RTL or LTR.